# Benefits of batman.js in angular.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, batman.js

I am planning to start a new complex project with ruby on rails, and I am currently thinking of which frontend-framework to use. I have never used one before.

Reading the docs, batman.js becomes really interesting. I would love to do things like "@post.comments" on the client side to get all comments for a given post - with nearly zero configuration. I am afraid of duplicated code if using a mvc-framework in the frontend and guess batman.js will reduce it. But in comparison to angular, batman does not gain from much support in the community (see [Google Trends](http://www.google.de/trends/explore#q=batman.js,%20angular.js&cmpt=q) for example).

So my question is, is it possible to have the benefits of a batman.js-app in an angular-application with a little configuration? Do you have any good links for a good rails-integration?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is relevant to the batman.js side. We have a couple Rails + batman.js apps in production already and we'll be launching another one soon. Here are the advantages and disadvantages we've found:

#### Advantages:

- Ruby & Rails-inspired syntax & architecture (eg, model associations, naming conventions, routing)
- Easily integrates with Rails (`batman-rails` gem, JSON REST communication, CoffeeScript, [Slim templates](http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2013/11/25/slim-templates-with-batmanjs-and-the-rails-asset-pipeline/))
- Easy to implement real-time updates (we're using Pusher)

#### Disadvantages:

- Low "googleability". Not as widely used as Ember, Angular, Backbone etc.
- Underdocumented. All our developers dive into the source from time to time.

For my part, I'm enjoying batman.js a lot and I'm trying to make up for the shortcomings by adding to documentation and being active on IRC, github and the google group. Good luck in your decision!